# pandas how to find percentage

Tags: sql, pandas

I'm studying PANDAS using Titanic data. (I'm real beginner)

My data is categorized with 'Survived', 'Sex', 'Age' etc.

I want to find the combined survival percentage of males over >=50 and women over >=40, with a single query.

Maybe I found sum of males over >=50 and women over >=40,

but I don't know how to make the percentage...

(Even I don't know whether the change (blank age filled) is reflected.)

How can I find the percentage using WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY? (I learned just these.. )

```
![Valid XHTML](<a href='ifh.cc/v-xAgYAO' target='_blank'><img src='ifh.cc/g/xAgYAO.png' border='0'></a>).
```

```
df_Mr_survived=sqldf("SELECT Age, Fare FROM df_titanic WHERE Title = 'Mr.' AND Survived = 1 ")
df_Mr_died=sqldf("SELECT Age, Fare FROM df_titanic WHERE Title = 'Mr.' AND Survived = 0")
df_Mrs_survived=sqldf("SELECT Age, Fare FROM df_titanic WHERE Title = 'Mrs.' AND Survived = 1")
df_Mrs_died=sqldf("SELECT Age, Fare FROM df_titanic WHERE Title = 'Mrs.' AND Survived = 0")

df_Mr_survived.fillna(df_Mr_survived["Age"].mean(), inplace=True)
df_Mr_died.fillna(df_Mr_died["Age"].mean(), inplace=True)
df_Mrs_survived.fillna(df_Mrs_survived["Age"].mean(), inplace=True)
df_Mrs_died.fillna(df_Mrs_died["Age"].mean(), inplace=True)
```

```
sqldf("SELECT COUNT(Sex) FROM df_titanic WHERE \
        (Sex='male' AND Age>=50 AND Survived=1) OR (Sex ='female' AND Age>=40 AND Survived=1)")
```

Comment: please include some data

Comment: @Deusdeorum ![Valid XHTML](<a href='https://ifh.cc/v-xAgYAO' target='_blank'><img src='https://ifh.cc/g/xAgYAO.png' border='0'></a>).

Comment: this is sample of data, and I already filled in the blank (age) with the avg of age. Other question asked me to create 4 df (Mr_survived, Mr_died, Mrs_survived, Mrs_died). Would it be related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I wouldn't split the dataframes into 4 separate ones unless you need to.

With that in mind I would do something like the following (there are 'better' ways to do this but this is more simple):

```
total_count = df.shape[0]
df = df.groupby(['Sex', 'Survived'])
df['percentage'] = (total_count / df.count()) * 100
```

This is untested so apologies in advance if its not 100%. But basically the .groupby() is saying group records where the Sex and the Survive status are the same. You then take the total_count divided by the .count() of records in that group and multiple that value by 100 to get your percentage. This should work, but if not look into if the .count() is giving the count of that group or the entire dataframe.

If you want to stick with your separate dataframes you're going to need to get the total number of records you have available. Assuming you have all the data in a single dataframe initially just use `total_count = df.shape[0]`. Then skip the group by step mentioned above and use `df['percentage'] = (total_count / df.count()) * 100` to get your percentage